# jQuery hover-based popup events for every product in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little problem with a function in jquery. I need to display a pop-up every time that a user is hover a Product. My products are in a list, and I would like to have a pop-up specified to every product in order to display it's title and description :

**This is the List of Products (displayed in a thumbnail)**

```
 <!-- This Div contains the List of Products -->
<ul class="thumbnails">

                @foreach (var thumbnail in Model.ForfaitsInThumbNail)
                {
    <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src= "@Url.Action("GetById", "ImageForfait", new { idForfait = thumbnail.Forfait.Id })" alt=""/>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h2 class="fontTitle">@thumbnail.Forfait.Titre</h2> <h5 class="fontYearHijri"> pour l'année @thumbnail.Forfait.AnneeHijri H </h5>

                                    .......
                                </div>
       <!-- This div should contain the pop-up for every Product -->
                            <div class='pop-up' id='pop-up'>    <h3>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Titre"</h3><p>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Description"</p></div>
                            </div>
    </div>
                   }
</ul>
```

This is my poor **jquery function** wich only works with one Product and not all of them in a list

```
<script>
$('.thumbnail').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function (e) {
    $('.pop-up').show()
        .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
        .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
        .appendTo('body');
}, function () {
    $('.pop-up').hide();
});
});
$('.thumbnail').each(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').mousemove(function(e) {
        $(".pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 10);
    });
});
```

This function has no errors, but it displays only the pop-up of the last Product, and that seems logic because it can't identify the div of the specified Product. So my question is, how can I implement this functionnality like I want to be (special pop-up for every Product)? Any Ideas ? Thank You :)

Comment: You're giving too many arguments to `.each()`. It only takes one argument, a function to be called on each element. The second argument is being ignored.

Comment: can you expalin more, please ? what's wrong with my function ?

Comment: My comment referred to the version before your edit.

Comment: I made an edit of the first version

Comment: I know. My comment referred to the `.each()` that you removed when you edited. So it is not relevant any more. You shouldn't make edits like that -- if you want to show a new version of the program, add it to the end, don't replace the original, since it confuses things.

Comment: I think that I passed the right argument, but still not working

Comment: Okay, there is an only one version now, this one

Comment: I agree, there were numerous problems with your initial code, but it's very confusing when you answer the question and you remove half of them and update the question

Comment: Yes, this version is much better, but still not workin unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

[I've update this answer by constructing a fiddle to show a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/rurp6/). In future, could you please provide a Fiddle where possible, as it saves us all a lot of time having to construct one for ourselves.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
// Note, this is important
$(document).ready(function () {    

    // We don't need an each, and include the e event handler
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function (e) {
        $('#pop-up').show()
            .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
            .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
            .appendTo('body');
    }, function () {
        $('#pop-up').hide();
    });
    $('.thumbnail').mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 10);
    });
});
```

Things you should also note: You don't need to have both an ID `#pop-up` and a class `.popup` on the same element, unless this is some special pop-up which inherits from the standard pop-up class. It looks like your ID/Class usage might be off, so just make sure that you're using IDs whenever something is unique, and classes when you have multiple instances.

Couple of fixes I made:

- **Always** wrap your jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` method, this will ensure that your DOM is fully loaded before the events are applied
- You forgot to include an event handler on your `hover` function, though I think you've updated your question with this included.

Comment: okay, I didn't noticed that you made a fiddle, thanks ! I will try to apply it on my work

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried my fiddle? I've just checked in FF, Chrome and IE 9 and 10, and it works on all of them.

Comment: The thumbnails shoudn't be implemented in javascript, because I have it in a Model, the dostuff() function is doin it in javascript, but the code that gets the List of Products should be in the HTML, you see ?

Comment: I understand, but I can't replicate an ASP for loop without doing that. Just don't copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to pass event object parameter on hover event

```
//do this 
...
$(this).hover(e){
  --
}
...
```

Hope this should work.

**If you notice you used (e.pageX) so where does (e) come from. It has to be passed as a parameter.**